# Oracle: How to use procedure local variables for "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" statements in procedures

Tags: oracle, procedure

We have a procedure starting with following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_id
  (id_ IN OUT number, type_ IN number)
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  local_id number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :local_id FROM dual';
  ...
```

Now if i execute this, the variable "local_id" is not filled with the next sequence value, but with null (although the sequence is raised by 1). If i change this to "... into local_id ..." i get ORA Error 1008 . What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

A local variable from the procedure can be bind to the query placeholder with `USING [OUT][IN]` clause:

```
  local_id number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'SELECT SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :local_id FROM dual'
     USING OUT local_id;
```

But for this query you don't need `execute immediate`, just do:

```
  local_id number;
BEGIN
  SELECT SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL into local_id FROM dual;
```

on Oracle 11g you can do it using the assignment operator:

```
  local_id number;
BEGIN
  local_id := SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :local_id FROM dual';
```

to

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SYS_LOCAL_ID_SERIAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM dual' into local_id;
```

I have tested this code in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT '||RTRIM(V_XUEWC)||' - '||RTRIM(V_XUAC)||' 
                    FROM table 
                    WHERE ACCOUNT_NUM='||RTRIM(V_ACC)||'';
```

While i am trying assign this result to a variable in execute immediate.. it doesnt return anything. V_XUEWC and V_XUAC are run time variables.